# Django objects.create produces more output than it should

Tags: python, django

There are two lists:

master_values:

```
[{<Truckdb: Truckdb object (141)>: [<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]}, {<Truckdb: Truckdb object (18)>: [<ItemBatch: Iphone>]}]
```

truck_objects:

```
[<truck_name: 17 Feet 6000>, <truck_name: Tempo 407 1500>]
```

When I run the following code it craetes more dispatchplan than it should:

```
for i in range(len(truck_objects)):
    for j in range(len(master_values)):
        if i == j:
            for q, w in master_values[j].items():
                for aa in range(len(w)):

                    print("len(w)  ",len(w))
                    DispatchPlan.objects.create(owner=request.user,
                            truck_type=container_object,
                            truck_name=truck_objects[i],
                            items=w[aa])
```

In this it created 5 dispatch plans when it should have created only two

Models.py

```
class DispatchPlan(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_quizzes')
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    truck_type = models.ForeignKey(truck_type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_type')
    truck_name = models.ForeignKey(truck_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispatch_name')

    items = models.ForeignKey(ItemBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')

class ItemBatch(models.Model):
    ttypes = (('Open', 'Open'), ('Container', 'Container'), ('Trailer', 'Trailer'), ('All', 'All'))
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uploaded_by')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pid = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    length = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    width = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    height = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    volume = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    truck_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0, choices=ttypes)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=now)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=now)
    rtd = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # ready to dispatch checkbox
    is_dispatched = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # item is dispatched or not
```

Comment: What is `items=w[aa]` doing here?

Comment: it is inserting items from master_values to the model

Comment: yes, but here you basically iterate over the ìtems` of the `master_values[j]`, and for all `aa` in `len(w)`, so the loops will result in creating more objects. It is not very clear to me why you expect this to create only two objects.

Comment: Oh my bad! How do I change that ? I just want to store items against the trucks, That is why I am using Foreign key

Comment: can you share the related models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Here, Can you please take time and check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766948/saving-an-object-in-django-table?noredirect=1#comment100095768_56766948     It contains the problem from beginning

Comment: but this does not include your `ItemBatch`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Update the question with models.py