# Replace Django Objects in a list with their corresponding id

Tags: python, django

i have a list of django objects

```
a = [<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]
```

Can I replace the objects with their id in ORM?

What I need:

```
a = [3,5,6]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Why have you created a new account for this question? This is clearly the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56770869/django-objects-create-produces-more-output-than-it-should etc.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is stored in the `pk` attribute. You thus can just map it with their `pk`, for example with list comprehension:

```
a = [item.pk for item in a]
```

Or you could use `attrgetter` from `operator`, in combination with `map` and `list`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

a = list(map(attrgetter('pk'), a))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the id, maybe you can optimize the ORM Queryset to request only this information.

```
ItemBatch.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list